# Calculating the barycenter of multiple triangles

Tags: matlab, vertex, centroid

I want to calculate each individual barycenter (centroid) of a list of triangles. Thus far I've managed to write this much :

```
 function Triangle_Source_Centroid(V_Epoch0, F_Epoch0)


        for i = 1:length(F_Epoch0)


        Centroid_X = F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,1),1)  + F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,1),2)  + F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,1),3);
        Centroid_Y = F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,2),1)  + F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,2),2)  + F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,2),3);
        Centroid_Z = F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,3),1)  + F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,3),2)  + F_Epoch0(V_Epoch0(:,3),3);

        Triangle_Centroid = [Centroid_X; Centroid_Y; Centroid_Z];

        end
end
```

it doesn't work, and only gives me an error message:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Comment: First step: check for zeroes in `V_Epoch0`.

Comment: what do you mean check for zeroes ? V_Epoch0 contains the coordinates of each vertex

Comment: There's your problem. You are using it as an index into `F_Epoch0`. Indices must be positive integers.

Comment: the above statement should in theory go through F_Epoch0 (contains all triangles participating points) and then pull the coordinates of the specific point from V_Epoch0, so that ill end up with (p1x + p2x + p3x)/3 ; same for y and z, and this must happen for ALL triangles in F_Epoch0

Comment: @AlanDeMoin consider accepting the answers that helped you, by clicking in the green tick below the arrows on the left.

Answer (score 2):

Given how the variables are named, I'm guessing that `V_Epoch0` is an N-by-3 matrix of vertices (X, Y, and Z for the columns) and `F_Epoch0` is an M-by-3 matrix of face indices (each row is a set of row indices into `V_Epoch0` showing which points make each triangle). Assuming this is right...

You can actually avoid using a for loop in this case by making use of [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html). For example, to get the X coordinates for every point in `F_Epoch0`, you can do this:

```
allX = reshape(V_Epoch0(F_Epoch0, 1), size(F_Epoch0));
```

Then you can take the [mean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) across the columns to get the average X coordinate for each triangular face:

```
meanX = mean(allX, 2);
```

And `meanX` is now a M-by-1 column vector. You can then repeat this for Y and Z coordinates:

```
allY = reshape(V_Epoch0(F_Epoch0, 2), size(F_Epoch0));
meanY = mean(allY, 2);
allZ = reshape(V_Epoch0(F_Epoch0, 3), size(F_Epoch0));
meanZ = mean(allZ, 2);
centroids = [meanX meanY meanZ];
```

And `centroids` is an M-by-3 matrix of triangle centroid coordinates.

**Bonus:**

All of the above can actually be done with just this one line:

```
centroids = squeeze(mean(reshape(V_Epoch0(F_Epoch0, :), [size(F_Epoch0, 1) 3 3]), 2));
```

Check out the documentation for [multidimensional arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) to learn more about how this works.